# Calling unknown method: frontend\models\NewsQuery::queryAll()

Tags: php, yii2

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $related = News::find();
    $related->andFilterWhere(['like', 'subject', $model->subject])
   ->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])
  ->queryAll();

    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $model,'related'=>$related
    ]);
}
```

I get this error:

> Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException
>   Calling unknown method: frontend\models\NewsQuery::queryAll()

Could someone tell me what I'm getting wrong?

Comment: I Already included News Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $related = News::find();
    $related->andFilterWhere(['like', 'subject', $model->subject])
   ->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC]);

    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $model,'related' => $related->all()
    ]);
}
```